# VSCode - Turn off auto closing bracket just for less than sign

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like auto closing tag behavior, but I am writing a math text in markdown and vscode add a greater than sign after my less than signs which is annoying me. How I can disable auto closing bracket just for <> type of bracket? Turning off all of them for markdown lanugage is sub optimal because I need auto closing of {} for latex inside of my markdown.

Comment: according to the settings, the auto close is language defined or never or always or beforeWhiteSpace